# JBoss AS 7 datasource configuration issue

Tags: java, jboss

I'm trying to retrieve a `dataSource` object from thr `jndi`-configuration inside the `standalone.xml`. I'm doing that as follows:

DataSource configuration:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/introDB" pool-name="introDS" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>
                        jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/hres
                    </connection-url>
                    <driver>
                        postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc4
                    </driver>
                    <pool>
                        <prefill>
                            false
                        </prefill>
                        <use-strict-min>
                            false
                        </use-strict-min>
                        <flush-strategy>
                            FailingConnectionOnly
                        </flush-strategy>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>
                            postgres
                        </user-name>
                        <password>
                            postgres
                        </password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <validate-on-match>
                            false
                        </validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>
                            false
                        </background-validation>
                        <useFastFail>
                            false
                        </useFastFail>
                    </validation>
                </datasource>
            </datasources>
```

Now, I'm trying to get the `dataSource` object programatically.

```
DataSource dataSource = null;
try {
    dataSource = (DataSource) jndi.lookup("java:jboss/datasources/introDB");
} catch (NamingException e) { }
```

But the code throws an Exception, like `NameNotFoundException`. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. What was wrong was setting up the `jndi-name` attribute to `java:jboss/datasources/introDB`. If you want to use jndi name like `datasources/introDB` you should type it without the `java:` prefix. So, the correct `jndi-name` is

```
jndi-name=datasources/introDB
```